# No suitable constructor found for Random(int, int)

Tags: java

I'm making a basic guessing game in unix, where I have a randomly chosen number from a range of possible numbers from 1 to 10, and the user has three chances to input a guess before "losing" or "winning". I'm relatively new to using unix, let alone vim, so if I could receive some help that would be very much appreciated. 
I keep getting these errors: "`no suitable constructor found for Random(int, int)`", as well as "`error: cannot find symbol`" for `guess, secGuess`, and `thirGuess`, even though I've instantiated them. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. here is my java code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Guess {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Random num = new Random(1,10);
        int value = num.nextInt(10);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
        int secGuess;
        int thirGuess;

        System.out.println("guess a number between 1 and 10");
        int tryCount = 0;


        guess = input.nextInt();
        if(guess == value) {
            System.out.println("Yay! You win!");
            noLoop();
        }
        if(guess > value) {
            System.out.println("Nope! Your number is too high, son!");
            tryCount++;
        }
        if(guess < value) {
            System.out.println("Nope! That number is too low!");
            tryCount++;
        }


        secGuess = input.nextInt();
        if(secGuess == value) {
            System.out.println("Yay! You win!");
        }
        if(secGuess > value) {
            System.out.println("Nope! Your number is too high, son!");
            tryCount++;
        }
        if(secGuess < value) {
            System.out.println("Nope! That number is too low!");
            tryCount++;
        }

        thirGuess = input.nextInt();
        if(thirGuess == value) {
            System.out.println("Yay! You win!");
            noLoop();
        }
        if(thirGuess > value) {
            System.out.println("Nope! Your number is too high, son!");
            tryCount++;
        }
        if(thirGuess < value) {
            System.out.println("Nope! That number is too low!");
            tryCount++;
        }

        if(tryCount>3) {
            System.out.println("You've exceeded the number of tries. Sorry, but you lose!");
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Well have you looked at the documentation for `Random`? Can you find a constructor with two `int` parameters? What would you expect it to do?

Comment: Unix and Vim have absolutely nothing to do with this.

Comment: After fixing the `Random` error, the only errors I get are to do with `input` and `noLoop` - which you *haven't* declared.

Comment: I'm entering this code in unix, while using vim. How does it have nothing to do with it? I'm giving context. And I see what I've done wrong for random - thanks for that. can I get a little insight on the errors surrounding input or noloop? Thank you.

Comment: @aniben It is ok to provide context, but this context should be related to the question. It doesn't matter which editor you used and it doesn't matter which operating system you're currently using, because this problem will occur on every OS. The OS might be relevant if you're trying to perform OS specific operations, like reading a file from a specific path. In your case *"java"* is the only tag you need :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no constructor of Random with two parameters. Replace

```
Random num = new Random(1,10);
```

with

```
Random num = new Random();
```

Next error in `guess = input.nextInt();`. There is nothing in the scope with name `input`. I suppose that you mean `sc`. There are three such errors.

Last one `noLoop();`. It is tricky to fix it because I have no idea vhat you mean. But can try to guess that you want to end your program. There are two way `return` and `System.exit(0)`

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Earlier, I said that the user input range should be between 1-10, but I think I didn't specify that 1 was a minimum... I think that's why I put it in random(). what should I do instead to make sure 1 is the minimum?

Comment: If you pass parameter to `nextInt` it will return value between 0 and your parameter. For example `nextInt(3)` can return 0, 1, 2. So if you write `nextInt(10) + 1` result will be exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need `tryCount` at all. Just print message without `if` at the end.

Comment: yeah, I actually just did that. I'm just complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to do this

```
Random num = new Random(); 
int value = num.nextInt() % 10;
```

Also, you can loop the tests 3 times instead of writing it 3 times. Like so -

```
while(tryCount<3){
        guess = input.nextInt() % 10;;
        if(guess == value) {
            System.out.println("Yay! You win!");
            break;
        }
        if(guess > value) {
            System.out.println("Nope! Your number is too high, son!");
            tryCount++;
        }
        if(guess < value) {
            System.out.println("Nope! That number is too low!");
            tryCount++;
        }
}
```